# show images of same width and height in cell of a table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using a table view(list view) there i am displaying images in cells,Images are displaying but not of same size its all of different size.I want all the images of same height and width. 
Can any one give me the code for that.
Tnx..

Comment: use custom cell or asynchrnousimageview for that.

Comment: manohar i am new to this please if possible give me a link to tutorial or code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell=nil;
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(2, 8, 40, 40);
        UIImage *img = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];
        UIImageView *customImage = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame] autorelease];
        customImage.image=img;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:customImage];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: custom image not found..what is custom image here??

Comment: tnx I'M POSSIBLE...bt it can't found image,what is image here??

Comment: how to get access token from Facebook ?? can u help??

Comment: I am getting userid from the another URL & I am saving that userId in a variable(USERID) I have tried http://abc.com/user/USERID/bookmarksdata
and http://abc.com/user/"+USERID+"/bookmarksdata,but it cant take user id.

Comment: how to do this please help I'M POSSIBLE.

Answer (score 0):

just add image with frame in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method like bellow..
you can also use `UIImageView` instead of `AsynchImageView`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
       cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ImageCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
              initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
              autorelease];
    } else {
    AsyncImageView* oldImage = (AsyncImageView*)
             [cell.contentView viewWithTag:999];
    [oldImage removeFromSuperview];
    }

    CGRect frame;
    frame.size.width=75; frame.size.height=75;
    frame.origin.x=0; frame.origin.y=0;
    AsyncImageView* asyncImage = [[[AsyncImageView alloc]
               initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    asyncImage.tag = 999;
    NSURL* url = [imageDownload
               thumbnailURLAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [asyncImage loadImageFromURL:url];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImage];

    return cell;
}
```

also [See This Demo](http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/) for your requirement

i hope this help you...

Comment: @deepak first try with demo which i post here the link bellow or also from here and see the tableview with whole images mate http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/...

Comment: I am getting userid from the another URL & I am saving that userId in a variable(USERID) I have tried http://abc.com/user/USERID/bookmarksdata
and http://abc.com/user/"+USERID+"/bookmarksdata,but it cant take user id.

Answer (score 0):

In tableview datasource method `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` provide frame for image view
`cell.imageView.frame`